# Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: php, apache, битрикс

Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin', перенёс сайт битрикса локально, теперь не открывает некоторые формы, в настройках апача и упоминания нет о X-frame, в настройках защита от фреймов тоже выключена,как это обойти ?

Comment: Что не открывается? Вы в iframe что грузите?

Comment: есть форма оплаты, там одно поле и две кнопки, внести оплату и удалить

Comment: просто грузится документ

Comment: причём если перейти из "Приложения" по этой форме то она открывается